# Reading values from cURL POST request

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to make a POST request using cURL in PHP. I have the code to make the POST request (from **index.php**) and I believe it is correct.

The next part is the API layer (**api.php**) which needs to extract the data from the POST request and this is where I am having issues. In the code, I am trying to read the value of the parameter q that I have passed using index.php.

Here's the code for both the files.

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
        $handle,
        array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost:8888/restAPI/api.php',
            'q' => 'getCompanyId',
            'post_fields' => 'q=getCompanyId',
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                'q' => 'getCompanyId'
            ),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    curl_close($handle);
?>
```

**api.php**

```
<?php
    require_once("Rest.inc.php");

    class API extends REST {

        public function processApi() {

            $func = $_REQUEST['q'];

            if((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0){
                $this->$func();
            }
            else{
                $this->response('',404); 
            // If the method not exist with in this class, response would be "Page not found".
            }
        }
        public function getCompanyId(){
            $dbhost = 'localhost:8888';
            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, 'root', 'root');

            if (! $conn) {
                die('Could not connect - ' . mysql_error());
            }

            $sql = 'SELECT companyId FROM Companies';
            mysql_select_db('IRSocialBackend');
            $executeSql = mysql_query($sql);

            while($data = mysql_fetch_array($executeSql)){
                echo $data['companyId'];
            }

        }
    }
    //echo "here";
    $api = new API;
    $api -> processApi();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a side note: your API is not RESTFUL. REST is not a matter of "making HTTP requests". Read up on it!

First mistake:

```
       array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost:8888/restAPI/api.php',
        'q' => 'getCompanyId',
        'post_fields' => 'q=getCompanyId',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            'q' => 'getCompanyId'
        ),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    )
```

Random "q" and "post_fields" is definitely *not* how you add fields to curlopt.

In **api.php**, you assign the following:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost:8888';
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, 'root', 'root');
```

I thought localhost:8888 was your webserver? localhost:3306 would be your MySQL server if it is on a default port.

The rest is hard to debug without knowing your table/DB structure.

Comment: Right now, I'm just trying to pass getCompanyId into the variable `$func` When I use `echo $func;` it does not print anything

Comment: @Ashish: then your CURL request is wrong! Simple as that. Can you `var_dump($_REQUEST)`? Bet you q isn't in there. If the array version of postfields doesn't work, try passing it a string.

Comment: you were right. Removing 'q' and 'random_fields' did solve the problem

Comment: How do I go about making the API RESTful ?

Comment: @AshishAgarwal: pretty good set of guidelines there: http://techblog.appnexus.com/2012/on-restful-api-standards-just-be-cool-11-rules-for-practical-api-development-part-1-of-2/